# ZK Listbox onselect issue

Tags: listbox, zk, zul

I am using Zk6.4 in my application i am getting a weird issue in listbox component ...You can check this  [here](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/6i5g90/35-Onselect)

How to reproduce the issue?.

1-Run the Fiddle code link given above

[image]

2-Click on any item

[image]

3-click on pick button of model Window 
 - A new tab Will open this tab contain a **listbox** and now this **listbox** **onselect** or Single item selection is not working.
[image]

4-Now New tab will open now Listbox OnSelect not working
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by schroet, this is caused by modal window, see [ZK Window Javadoc](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Window.html#MODAL)

As a workaround, you can modify the doPickDocumentRSN method in PopUpViewModel.java as below:

```
    public void doPickDocumentRSN(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component comp) {
        Map maps = new HashMap();
        maps.put("PARENT_VIEW", comp);
        maps.put("peopleTabArg", new TabArguement(TabArguement.TabMode.PICK));

        UserInterfaceViewModel.addAnyTab(maps, "Tab2", "tab2.zul");
        comp.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I dont think it is an issue, you don't have any onClick or onSelect attributes in your tab2.zul.

tab1.zul:

```
<listitem onClick="@command('doPickDocument',documentRSN=each.documentRSN)">
    <listcell label="@load(each.documentRSN)" />
    <listcell label="@load(each.documentDesc)" />
    <listcell label="@load(each.documentOrder)" />
</listitem>
```

tab2.zul:

```
<listitem >
   <listcell label="@load(each.documentRSN)" />
       <listcell label="@load(each.documentDesc)" />
   <listcell label="@load(each.documentOrder)" />
</listitem>
```

**Edit to first Comment:**

my bad.

Use mode="overlapped" for your popup_window.zul window. Becuase it's modal you can't interact with other components (windows) until you close your modal window.

Comment: Sorry man you did not get it please check Tab1 here you can select anyitem color will change but same thing will not happen with tab2 i tab2 color change of item will move with mouse

Comment: Use mode="overlapped" for your popup_window.zul window.